# bower not running through yeoman

Tags: javascript, http, github, yeoman, bower

I've been looking around and asking come coworkers, but cannot figure this out.

I'm trying to trigger the bower install through a yeoman generator, but get the errors below:

[image]

I thought using the command: `git config --global url."https://" instead of git://` would get around the proxies we set up, but still a no go.

A coworker also pointed out a bug fix(https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1413), but that didnt seem to do anything as well.

Yeoman code:

```
  var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');
  var bower = require('bower');

 module.exports = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({
    priorityName: function () {

    },
    init: function(){
        console.log("init");
    },
    createStructure: function () {
        this.mkdir("commonCode");
        this.mkdir("commonCode/service");
        this.mkdir("commonCode/util");
        this.mkdir("commonCode/views");
        console.log("createStructure");
    },
    restructureDir: function(){
        console.log("restruct");   
    },
    installDependencies: function(){
        this.bowerInstall();
        console.log("install");
    }
 });
```

Any insight is appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: Did you try `git config --global http.proxy http://user:pass@server:port`?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Unfortunately a proxy would cause security issues for the company.